# C++ Creating an Balanced Binary Search Tree Using Array Structure

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, binary-search-tree, nodes

am tasked with storing a binary tree within a vector. Within each node is stored an int ID, int Age, and a string name.

The nodes are stored and organized within the vector by ID.

When storing the binary tree within a vector, I am using the algorithm 2i and 2i+1 to dictate a node's left and right child respectively.

I have managed to create an insert method that I believe satisfies these conditions, however for some reason, when attempting to print the values of my vector, I appear to get negative values. For this particular example, I insert the following values

100 21 Stan

50 30 Phil

I attempt to place another node

30 31 Alice

According to sources, **this causes the tree to become unbalanced.**

So I am attempting to create a balanced binary search tree using nodes stored in a vector. Previously I created an unbalanced tree using this previous insertion structure. However, **I don't exactly understand what a balanced binary search tree is**

So my questions are as followed:

1. What exactly is a balanced binary search tree?
2. What would you suggest I should change in my insert function to encourage the creation of a balanced tree?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int index = 0;

struct Node
{
    int ID = -1;
    int age = -1;
    string name = "";

    Node()
    {


    }

    Node(int id, int Age, string nm)
    {
        this->ID = id;
        this->age = Age;
        this->name = nm;
    }
};

vector<Node> binaryTree;


BST::BST()
{

}





void BST::insert()
{
    unsigned int ID;
    int AGE;
    string NAME;
    int root = 0;

    bool success = false;
    cout << "Please enter the ID number, age and name:" << endl;


    cin >> ID >> AGE >> NAME;

    Node *tree = new Node(ID, AGE, NAME);



    if (!binaryTree.empty())
    {
        do
        {
            if (tree->ID > binaryTree.at(root).ID && binaryTree.at(root).ID != 0)
            {
                root = 2 * root + 2;
                if (root >= binaryTree.size()) binaryTree.resize((2 * root + 2 + 1) * 5);

            }

            if (tree->ID < binaryTree.at(root).ID && binaryTree.at(root).ID != 0)
            {
                root = 2 * root + 1;
                if (root >= binaryTree.size()) binaryTree.resize((2 * root + 2 + 1) * 5);

            }

            if (binaryTree.at(root).ID == -1)
            {
                binaryTree[root] = *tree;
                success = true;
            }
        } while (!success);
    }

    if (binaryTree.empty())
    {
        binaryTree.push_back(*tree);
    }

    delete tree;

}
```

Comment: Discussions about Balanced Binary Trees is too big for a simple Q&A site like StackOverflow.  Search the internet for "c++ balance binary tree example" or "c++ balanced binary tree tutorial".

Comment: Hint:  a binary tree and all linked lists using an array or vector have the same algorithm as one using pointers.  The difference is that the array version uses array indices for links instead of pointers.

Comment: Hint:  Get the tree working as a binary tree first.  Then add in the balancing.  This allows you to focus on balancing issues without having to also worry about binary tree issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), the most extreme form of a balanced binary tree (all indices in the array must be full for the next one to be used).

The `2i`, `2i+1` algorithm you are using should work just fine (remember to keep the 0 index unused).

To insert you can do the following:

1) Add the new element at the first unused index in the array.

2) Use the `upheap` algorithm for it. The way this works is that you compare the element with its parent, and swap depending on the property of the tree (e.g. in max heap if child > parent). You do this recursively until the root of the tree (index 1). This takes `O(log n)` time.

This should give you a perfectly balanced binary tree with an array implementation.

Comment: please give code as answer, it is not literture

Comment: @myworldbox nope